# Очистить список не установленных до конца пакетов KUbuntu 12.04

Tags: apt-get, java

Привет.

После попытки установки Adobe Flash Player из стороннего репозитория по инструкции http://ubuntovod.ru/soft/oracle-java-7-ubuntu-12-04.html очень сильно пожалел.

Установка так и нее произошла, зато появился не до конца установленный пакет. когда пытаюсь его установить или удалить получаю:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove oracle-java7-installerЧтение списков пакетов… ГотовоПостроение дерева зависимостей       Чтение информации о состоянии… ГотовоПакеты, которые будут УДАЛЕНЫ:  oracle-java7-installerобновлено 0, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 1 пакетов, и 0 пакетов не обновлено.не установлено до конца или удалено 1 пакетов.После данной операции, объём занятого дискового пространства уменьшится на 82,9 kB.Хотите продолжить [Д/н]? y(Чтение базы данных ... на данный момент установлено 185582 файла и каталога.)Удаляется пакет oracle-java7-installer ...update-alternatives: ошибка: неизвестный аргумент «dev»dpkg: не удалось обработать параметр oracle-java7-installer (--remove): подпроцесс установлен сценарий pre-removal возвратил код ошибки 2Downloading...--2012-05-08 17:36:02--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gzПреобразование адреса download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 87.245.215.55, 87.245.215.47Подключение к download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|87.245.215.55|:80... соединились.Запрос HTTP послан, ожидание ответа... 302 Moved TemporarilyАдрес: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gz [переход]--2012-05-08 17:36:02--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gzПреобразование адреса edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 2.18.234.174Подключение к edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|2.18.234.174|:443... соединились.Запрос HTTP послан, ожидание ответа... 302 Moved TemporarilyАдрес: http://download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.html [переход]--2012-05-08 17:36:03--  http://download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.htmlПодключение к download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|87.245.215.55|:80... соединились.Запрос HTTP послан, ожидание ответа... 200 OKДлина: 5307 (5,2K) [text/html]Сохранение в каталог: ««./jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gz»».     0K .....                                                 100% 75,3M=0s2012-05-08 17:36:03 (75,3 MB/s) - «./jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gz» сохранен [5307/5307]Download done.sha256sum mismatch jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gzOracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.dpkg: ошибка при очистке - подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 1При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки: oracle-java7-installerE: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

При любой установке apt-get пытается закончить установку, и выдает ошибку. что бесит.apt-get clean и apt-get autoclean пробовал. apt-get purge выдает то же самое.

**UPD: Вылечил с помощью:**

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info/sudo rm oracle-java7-installer*sudo apt-get remove oracle-java7-installer
```

Answer (score 1):

Лучше было бы отредактировать в этом каталоге скрипт который выдаёт ошибку, а так потерялись данные об установленных файлах, и фактически они не были удалены из системы.Или использовать dpkg:

```
sudo dpkg -r --force-remove-reinstreq oracle-java7-installer
```